# Rofi icons not showing on void-linux + i3 + Papirus icon theme

Tags: i3, icons, void-linux, rofi

After I installed the [papirus-icon-theme](https://github.com/void-linux/void-packages/tree/master/srcpkgs/papirus-icon-theme) package, I setup rofi configuration like this:

```
rofi.theme: ~/.vendor/gruvbox-rofi/gruvbox-dark.rasi
rofi.show-icons: true
```

At rofi launch, I can see a space for the app icons, but nothing appears.

But the icon theme seems to be well detected:

```
❯ screenfetch -n
 sullivan@sweethome
 OS: Void Linux 
 Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.19.27_1
 Uptime: 1h 51m
 Packages: 663
 Shell: zsh 5.7.1
 Resolution: 1920x1080
 WM: i3
 GTK Theme: gnome [GTK2/3]
 Icon Theme: Papirus
 Font: Sans 10
 CPU: Intel Core i7-6700 @ 8x 4GHz [61.0°C]
 GPU: GeForce GTX 970
 RAM: 4869MiB / 15967MiB
```

I also added `rofi.icon-theme: Papirus` without success.

What I'm missing? I'm pretty sure I don't have to install a complete desktop environment to get this working, but I don't really know what else to do.

The way rofi is launch with i3:

```
bindsym $mod+d exec rofi -show run
```

The Rofi current version:

```
❯ rofi -version
Version: 1.5.2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of 'run' use 'drun' instead.

should look like:

```
bindsym $mod+d exec rofi -show drun
```